# Bootstrap model in liferay

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, liferay

I build a portlet in Liferay with many bootstrap modal. But my problem is I can not click on datetimepicker or some button. I found the reason is "modals cover picker although it is hidden". I get over it by show all modal then hide them==> picker work well.
But at start time when I load my page, modal show in a short time=>new problem.
I used to hide modal without show them but it not work. Can you show me how to get over it.

Comment: unless you post your code here or make a fiddle for your work no one can help.

Comment: And either you use the Bootstrap version integrated into the latest Liferay 6.2, which is [Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/), or you exclude the Liferay CSS files and use your own version - in which case Liferay is irrelevant for the problem.